# azure ad b2c custom policy - ROPC

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

as part of the "SignUpOrSignIn" userJourney, i would like to call MyAPI and run some business logic.

to accomplish that, i added a couple of orchestration steps to the "SignUpOrSignIn" userJourney after the user has successfully authenticated.

Step 1) make a simple http request to azure ad b2c token endpoint and get an access token to MyAPI

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token
username    <user-name>
password    <password>
grant_type  password
scope   <MyAPI Scope> 
client_id   <application-id of the client that has been granted access to MyAPI>
response_type   token id_token
```

Step 2) use the access token from the previous response to call MyAPI.

I got this working. However, in Step (1), when i make the http request to get the access token, i am having to provide a hard coded username and password in the http request.

Is there a way to use the values of the username and password that were entered as part of "SignUpOrSignIn" to get the access token?

Thanks,
-Sashi.

Comment: The username and password should be available as claims at that point I think? The login-nonInteractive technical profile uses those claims to log in the user using a similar approach.

Comment: Why are you doing this? ROPC Policy already returns an access token for the requested scope. And if you use a normal Sign In/Up Policy, it does too. Why make this ROPC call within the Sign In/Up policy itself? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

Comment: Hi sashi, from my experience I am only able to retain the password claim in the technical profile that uses login-noninteractive. After that technical profile, the password claim is lost ( I believe due to security reasons.) If you would like to call a Rest API with the user's password, I would recommend adding a REST technical profile as a validation step instead of an orchestration step. Or have a output claims transformation that copies the password claim to a different claim that won't expire.

Comment: i only want to run the business logic on Sign Up.

Comment: @juunas the validation tech profile login-nonInteractive gets initiated by tech profile SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email. I think that profile gets used for sign in.

Comment: @JasSuri i think its possible to get the access token via a normal Sign In by mentioning the MyAPI scope. i am not sure how to obtain the access token when sign Up. How would you go about getting the access token and making an API call on SIgn Ups?

Comment: @ChristopherNorris tried the copy claim, Didnt work for me. I'd appreciate if you could give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: Its a simple use case..do you guys agree?..when someone signs up..make a call to your API..run  some business logic..confirm registration based on API response...

However, need access tokens to talk to the API...the way to do that is using the ROPC...and here there is no alternative to typing the password in plain text within the custom policy.

Comment: Scenario is really unclear still and your last comment doesn’t tie in with the original post. Maybe you can rephrase by asking what you are trying to do overall.